# Unzip archive in .Net CORE 1.0

Tags: c#, .net, zip, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Core 1.0 project. I want to stay on the **dnxcore50** and the **dnx451** at the same time. Which brings me to the following issue now:

How can I unzip a zip archive from the filesystem to a directory?

```
"System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
"System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.0-beta-22816"

"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.IO": ""
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.IO": "4.0.10-beta-*"
      }
    }
  }
```

With that configuration in the project.json I'm now able to get a GZipStream but I have no idea how to store that stream to a directory. Unfortunately the ZipFile object in **System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory() method doesn't exsists** in the core framework :/.

**UPDATE:**

I now included it that way and removed it from the overall dependencies:

```
"frameworks": {
"dnx451": {
  "dependencies": {
    "System.IO.Compression.ZipFile": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
  }
},
"dnxcore50": {
  "dependencies": {
    "System.IO.Compression.ZipFile": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
  }
}
```

When I run the application using core it works as expected, but running it with the .net framework 4.6 I crashes with the following exeception during runtime:

n unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Compression.ZipFile, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Hm, [are you sure](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile/ref/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.cs/#L15)?

Comment: thx for your answer. I found my mistake. I used the last stable release of System.IO.Compression.ZipFile 4.0.0 but it seems it has been added in 4.0.1-beta-23516 @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: updated my question. Can you please help me again? @JoachimIsaksson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependencies you require in your project.json are as follows.

```
"frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.IO.Compression": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem":  "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.IO.Compression.ZipFile": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
```

The dependenices in the root of project.json are for any packages that work with all runtimes you are using.

The frameworkAssemblies in the .net runtime are the same references you would add in a normal csproj based project. You can find the assemblies here if you are not sure what to add. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt472912(v=vs.110).aspx. You would use the dependencies section here for any net specific references.

When it comes to dnxcore50 the dependencies references come straight from nuget but you can use the intellisense to find these.

More information about project.json can be found here https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file

Comment: thx, now its working as expected, but where do I know which frameworksAssemblies I have to add? I don't know how this works. Is there some documentation for the project.json?

Comment: I have updated my answer with some more information leave another comment if your not sure about anything

Comment: Thx, and why is it named frameworkAssemblies and the other time dependencies?

Comment: frameworkAssemblies are for any assemblys that come with the framework itself this is more for .net as .netcore all of its framework assemblies are on nuget and dependencies are for any projects in your solution or packages on nuget