# How to unrar an archive in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, compression, .net-core

Is there a library builtin that could be used to extract `rar` files in dotnet core?  I found something to extract zip files, but nothing for `rar` files.  Used 7zip in 4.5

Comment: It is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952962/unzip-archive-in-net-core-1-0

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban The answer you provided doesn't mention .rar archieves

Comment: Do you get an answer to this question?!

Answer (score 6):

It seems like there is nothing builtin to extract multipart rar files in .net. There are libraries for .net but not dotnet core as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1025934/6583901). (maybe they can easily be ported)

The `ZipFile` class from `System.IO.Compression` supports both .zip and .rar (not multipart) archives.

You can open an archive like this:

```
using(ZipArchive za = ZipFile.OpenRead(strPath))  
{
    //do something with `za.Entries` or with other properties
}
```

Comment: This I believe works for a single rar but didn't work for a multipart rar file

Comment: @AsadHasnaini You could try to port the [C# (.net) interface for 7-Zip archive dlls](http://dev.nomad-net.info/articles/sevenzipinterface) library which is in the answer I edited into the post

Comment: Doesn't even seem to work with non-multipart rar files either.